# using for loop in python but some values missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

x
array([10,  3,  8,  0, 19, 10, 11,  9, 10,  6,  0, 12,  7, 14, 17])

so I am trying to create a new array, x[i] is true only if x[i] is a positive multiple of 3.

```
mask_mult_3=[]
for i in x:
    if i >0:
        if i %3==0:
            i=True
        else:
            i=False
        mask_mult_3.append(i)
np.array(mask_mult_3)
```

the result is 
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
        True, False, False, False])

I have 15 values in x, but now the result only have 13 values, what caused this and how can I solve it based on my original script?

Comment: You have two `0`'s that you are ignoring with your condition     `if i >0:`

Comment: Get rid of the outer `if`, and replace the inner condition with `if i > 0 and i % 3 == 0`.  Right now you're skipping the entries that are `<= 0`, so in your example, you effectively strip the `0` entries from the input.

Comment: list comprehension would work well here - `mask_multi_3 = [True if i %3 ==0 else False for i in x]`

Answer (score 0):

Because it is `if i >0:` Loop will not run the `append()` fuction when i = 0;

You could change `if i >0:` into -> `if i >=0:`, or remove this condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement i>0 try using i>=0 because your list has number 0 in it and i>0 takes numbers strictly greater than 0.

```
mask_mult_3=[]
for i in x:
    if i >=0:
        if i %3==0:
            i=True
        else:
            i=False
        mask_mult_3.append(i)
np.array(mask_mult_3)
```